# Find the range of $f(x) = 3x^4 - 16x^3 + 18x^2 + 5$ without applying differential calculus

Tags: polynomials, optimization, systems-of-equations, maxima-minima

> Find the range of $f(x) = 3x^4 - 16x^3 + 18x^2 + 5$ without applying differential calculus.

I tried to express $$f(x)=3x^4-16x^3+18x^2+5=A(ax^2+bx+c)^2+B(ax^2+bx+c)+C $$ which is a quadratic in $ax^2+bx+c$ which itself is quadratic in $x$. Comparing coefficients, we get

$$Aa^2=3 \tag{1}$$

$$2abA=-16$$

$$A(b^2+2ac)+aB=18$$

$$2bcA+bB=0$$

$$Ac^2+Bc+C=5$$

But I felt its very lengthy to solve these equations. Any hints?

Comment: Are you going to further express $f(x)$ as $A(u-\alpha)^2+\beta$ (where $u=ax^2+b+c$)? If this method works, then you will end up with $f(x)$ attaining its absolute miinimum when $ax^2+bx+c=u-\alpha=0$. But this implies that either the graph of $y=f(x)$ has two lowest points with same $y$-coordinate but different $x$-cooridnate, or $fx)=A(x-\phi)^4+\beta$ for some $\beta$. This is not true for a general quartic polynomial.

Comment: there is no max, so, the question is to find its minimum

Comment: The system of equations you have are inconsistent.

Comment: I guess $\,f'(x)=0\,$ counts as calculus, but how about $\,\gcd(f,f')\,$ which is essentially equivalent to the discriminant.

Answer (score 8):

Let us consider the minimum of $f(x)$ as $k$. Then $f(x)-k$ has at least one repeated root. That is

$$f(x)-k=3x^4-16x^3+18x^2+5- k=3(x-a)^2(x^2+bx+c)$$

Expand and equate coefficients, you get $k=5-3a^2 c$, and

$$3(b-2a)=-16 \\ 3(c+a^2-2ab)=18 \\ a(ab-2c)=0$$

From third equation if $a=0$, then $k=5$. For $a \neq 0$ combinig three equations gives $a^2=4a-3$. Thus $a=1, 3$.

$a=1$ leads to $c=-\frac{5}{3}$, and $k=5-3(-\frac{5}{3})=10$.

$a=3$ gives $c=1$, and $k=5-27=-22$.

Therefore minimum is $k=-22$.

Comment: Hello. Why should f(x) - k have at least one repeated root?

Answer (score 7):

The range is $[k,+\infty)$ where $k$ is the minimum value  such that the inequality
$$
3x^4-16x^3+18x^2+5\ge k
$$
is true for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and this is the minimum value $k$ such that the equation 
$$
3x^4-16x^3+18x^2+5- k=0
$$
has a double solution, that is the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of $3x^4-16x^3+18x^2+5- k$ is null.

The calculation of the [discriminant for a quartic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_4) is a bit ''heavy'', but [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discriminant%203x%5E4-16x%5E3%2B18x%5E2%2B5) gives:

$$\Delta= -6912(k-5)(k-10)(k+22)$$

so the minimum value is $k=-22$.